# 'Vue' is not defined in my custom ShopWare 6 Javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, window, shopware

Vue.js is added in my head tag:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`

I am building some custom Vue logic into my [ShopWare 6 website](https://www.shopware.com/en/products/shopware-6/) (not with Vue storefront yet).

In my custom ShopWare 6 [javascript plugin](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/js-storefront-plugin?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to) file `vue-input-number/vue-input-number.plugin.js` I have:

```
import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';

export default class VueInputNumber extends Plugin {
    init() {

        window.Vue = Vue;

        const App = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!',
            },
            delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
        })
    }
}
```

When I compile this `.js` file `./psh.phar storefront:build` I get an error:

```
error  'Vue' is not defined                      no-undef
error  'App' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
error  'Vue' is not defined                      no-undef
```

What do I have to do, so I can make new Vue instances in my Javascript files?

Comment: Is `vue-input-number/vue-input-number.plugin.js` file added before `/dist/vue.js` file in head tag?

Comment: No. vue.js is in the `<head>` tag. `vue-input-number/vue-input-number.plugin.js` should be compiled into all.js which is below </body> tag. I get this error while I want to compile this new .js file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running into some ESLint errors there because Vue is unknown to the Shopware 6 webpack config in the Storefront. You can try to add `Vue` to the `.eslintrc`:

```
// platform/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
    // ...

    'globals': {
        'gtag': true,
        'Vue': true <-- Add Vue here
    },

    // ...
};
```

Or you can disable ESLint for the line which uses `Vue`:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
    },
    delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
})
```

Comment: Ok thanks that's make sense. Can I just somehow create a new `.eslintrc.js` file in my custom plugin custom/plugins/MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/src ? And regarding your example: `'Vue': true <-- Add Vue here`. How do I add Vue here?